# Метод шифрования DES

Tags: криптография, php, шифрование

При помощи php необходимо зашифровать строку, используя алгоритм DES и схему шифрования ECB 
пример:

```
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, 'ABCDEFGH', 'E272B2F96198FACE', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)
```

Этот код выводит результат:

> > +��Iin1/n��떇

Пробовал разные кодировки, ничего не меняется. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Для верности попробуйте расшифровать результат обратно.

Comment: А что именно вы хотите увидеть? HEX-представление?

Answer (score 1):

Ну а чего же вы хотели то? Шифрование возвращает чистый бинарный массив. Чтобы ее отобразить надо представить в виде 16-тиричной строки.